# How to run Playwright in headless mode?

Tags: vue.js, vite, playwright

I created a new Vue app using `npm init vue@latest` and selected Playwright for e2e tests. I removed **firefox** and **webkit** from projects in the `playwright.config.ts` file, so it will only use **chromium**.

Running `npm run test:e2e` works fine, the process exists with a success code.

When forcing the tests to fail by modifying the `./e2e/vue.spec.ts` file the output is

[image]

but the process does not exit with an error code, it still opened browser windows and so CI environments would freeze.

I searched [the docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-cli) for a specific flag e.g. "headless" and tried `--max-failures -x` but that didn't help.

How can I tell Playwright to run in headless mode and exit with an error code when something failed?

---

Since *playwright.config.ts* already makes use of `process.env.CI` I thought about replacing `reporter: "html",` with `reporter: [["html", { open: !process.env.CI ? "on-failure" : "never" }]],`

but which arguments should I add to the script `"test:e2e:ci": "playwright test",` to ensure `process.env.CI` is set?

---

**Update**

I tried to run the script inside my CI environment and it seems to work out of the box ( I don't know how it sets the CI environment flag but the pipeline did not freeze )

```
  - name: Install Playwright Browsers
    run: npx playwright install --with-deps

  - name: Check if e2e tests are passing
    run: npm run test:e2e
```

If any test fails it exists with an error code

Answer (score 1):

It's serving the html report and asking to press 'Ctr+C' to quite.You can disable it using below configuration.

```
// playwright.config.ts
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  reporter: [ ['html', { open: 'never' }] ],
};
export default config;
```

Refer - [Report Doc](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#html-reporter)

Issue - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9702

Comment: so I could try this? `reporter: [["html", { open: !process.env.CI ? "on-failure" : "never" }]],` Is it possible to set the env variable in the npm script?

Comment: I tried `NODE_ENV=CI playwright test` but that didn't work

Comment: and `set NODE_ENV=CI& playwright test`

Comment: It need to be something like  'set CI=true & playwright test'  or 'set CI=false & playwright test'. You are trying to access 'CI' environment variable in 'process.env.CI'

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: I moved this question to a new post ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614280/how-to-set-process-env-variable-inside-npm-script

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer above, you can set headless: true in the 'use' block of the config which is above the projects block.  Anything set at that level will apply to all projects unless you specifically override the setting inside a project specific area:

```
// playwright.config.ts
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  reporter: [ ['html', { open: 'never' }] ],
  use: {
    headless: true,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
      },
    },
  },
};
export default config;
```

Comment: this one here `reporter: [ ['html', { open: 'never' }] ]` is important. `headless` did not help. Please have a look at this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611417/how-to-run-playwright-in-headless-mode#comment131701139_74611775