# How to set process.env variable inside npm script?

Tags: javascript, npm, vite

I created a new Vue app ( based on Vite ) using `npm init vue@latest` and selected Playwright for e2e tests. The generated configuration file provides a field to set the headless mode

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  // ...
  use: {
    // ...
    headless: !!process.env.CI,
  },
  // ...
};
```

but I don't know how to set this env variable. The generated script

```
"test:e2e": "playwright test",
```

does not run in headless mode. So I tried to set this variable before running it. Scripts I tried

- `"test:e2e:ci": "NODE_ENV=CI playwright test"`
- `"test:e2e:ci": "set NODE_ENV=CI& playwright test"`
- `"test:e2e:ci": "set NODE_ENV=CI & playwright test"`
- `"test:e2e:ci": "set CI=true & playwright test"`
- `"test:e2e:ci": "set NODE_ENV=CI && playwright test"`
- `"test:e2e:ci": "set CI=true && playwright test"`

Does someone know how to fix the ci script?

---

This is the generated config file

https://pastebin.com/tbXNuscy

there are many uses of `process.env.CI` and I'm looking for a way to set this on the fly ( inside the npm script where I need it )

Comment: There is a npm package called ```cross-env``` that might suit your need

Comment: It's `&&` not a single ampersand. Example: `"start": "set NODE_ENV=YOURENV && tagove start"`

Comment: @vicki I tried `npx cross-env CI=true` but that didn't help

Comment: @node_modules unfortunately that didn't work, I added your suggestions to the list

Answer (score 1):

You may add a `.env` file in your project folder

**.env**

```
NODE_ENV=CI
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default ({ mode }) => {

    process.env = {
        ...process.env,
        ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())
    };

    return defineConfig({
        // ...
    });
};
```

Then you can use the configs in `.env` like below:

in **vite.config.js** itself, use `process.env`

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default ({ mode }) => {

    process.env = {
        ...process.env,
        ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())
    };

    return defineConfig({
        server: {
            hmr: {
                // you may use process.env here
                host: process.env.VITE_APP_HOST,
            },
        },
    });
};
```

in the other files, use `import.meta.env` instead

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE;
```

**Notice**:

If the config is needed on the client side, add a `VITE_` prefix, or it can't be seen on the client side.

[more details here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files)

---

update:

you may use different [modes](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes) for your test environment and the others

**.env.test**

```
CI=true
```

**package.json**

```
"test:e2e": "playwright test --mode=test",
```

**.env.prod**

```
CI=false
```

**package.json**

```
"prod": "vite build --mode=prod",
```

Comment: but when using an `.env` file it will always use the CI environment, right?

Comment: I updated my question with a configuration example

Comment: I don't think I should create my own setup... If Vite already generated such a vite configuration using `process.env.CI` there should be a way to tell Vite to use it, no?